# Linux: Why is ARP not answered via VLAN Bridge

Tags: linux, vlan, bridge, qemu, arp

**Our Goal**

We want to run a server with several QEMU VMs, some of the VMs should be connected to separate VLANs. The host is connected to a switch via bonding and should have a VLAN-aware bridge where all VMs are connected (like a real switch with VLANs but in software). The bridge itself is assigned the host's IP, and this host should be able to access the VMs. To protect the host/bridge/primary LAN some of the VM's interfaces on the host should be filtered (incoming & outgoing) using iptables (iptables outside of the VMs).

**Our Setup**

The test server is a Supermicro machine with 4 ports and Ubuntu 20.4 server. This is connected to a small Zyxel GS-1900 switch which in turn is connected to our LAN network (HP infrastructure). We started with the PVID 1 and a VLAN 55 that is already set up on the stack and the WLAN APs. The switch ports have PVID 1 and tagged VLAN 55 set. On the physical network everything should be ok. For the tests I did not even set up the VM, it is just the plain OS where I assigned an IP out of the VLAN 55 to the VLAN interface. We are not using netplan, NetworkManager or systemd config. We just use /etc/network/interfaces.

**Our Problem**

I cannot get the Ubuntu host with the VLAN-aware bridge to play with the VLAN. A ping into VLAN 55 results in ARP who-has - and that's it. I can see it on the VLAN interface (tcpdump) but I cannot see it on any other interface. Why is ARP not going through? And if ARP would go through, will the rest be working?

**What we did**

We tried everything by hand and we simply have no clue what we are missing. We even re-installed the machine. We're stuck.

These are the *commands* that - we believe - should work.  But they don't:

```
ip link add bond0 type bond
ip link set bond0 type bond miimon 100 mode balance-alb
ip link set eth0 down
ip link set eth0 master bond0
ip link set bond0 up
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
ip link set bond0 master br0
ip link add venet0 type veth peer venet0_0
ip link set venet0 master br0
bridge vlan add dev venet0 vid 55 master
bridge vlan del dev venet0 vid 1
bridge vlan add dev bond0 vid 55
ip address add dev venet0_0 192.168.55.0/24
ip address add dev br0 10.233.202.2/22
ip link set venet0 up
ip link set venet0_0 up
```

We see no errors, the result looks as we believe it is correct. The br0 interface can ping the local VLAN 55 interface and it can ping into the world if the default gw is set. But the VLAN interface can not ping anything except itself. The problem is that there is no arp response because arp is never seen on any other port.

Output of *ip link show* is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:33:8a:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:33:8a:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:33:8a:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:33:8a:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

15: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:33:8a:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

16: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:33:8a:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.233.202.2/22 scope global br0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

17: venet0_0@venet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether de:d7:d5:3c:ed:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.55.5/24 scope global venet0_0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

18: venet0@venet0_0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:48:95:e5:9a:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output of *bridge vlan show*:

```
port    vlan ids
bond0    1 PVID Egress Untagged
         55

br0      1 PVID Egress Untagged

venet0   55 Egress Untagged
```

*route -n* shows:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.233.202.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.55.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 venet0_0
```

And *tcpdump -nlpvvvi venet0_0* shows (.254 is available via physical switch):

```
14:38:47.657112 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.55.254 tell 192.168.55.5, length 28
```

The configuration shown above is found in several places on the internet and is reported as working. What are we doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

a. In tcpdump I just saw a packet coming in to venet0_0 from an access point telling that a client has roamed. Strange...

b. Added the following really trivial picture

[how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd54U.png)

**EDIT 2 - SOLUTION:**

```
ip link add bond0 type bond
ip link set bond0 type bond miimon 100 mode balance-alb
ip link set eth0 master bond0
ip link set bond0 up
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
ip link set bond0 master br0
ip link add venet0 type veth peer venet0_0
ip link set venet0 master br0
bridge vlan add dev venet0 vid 55 untagged pvid
bridge vlan del dev venet0 vid 1
bridge vlan add dev bond0 vid 55 master
ip link set venet0 up
ip link set venet0_0 up
```

And this was finally used in /etc/network/interfaces

Thanks to Nikita Kipriyanov

**EDIT 3 - /etc/network/interfaces**

This is the /etc/network/interfaces portion I made out of this. Regarding the comment by Nikita it seems as if the file can be written without all the post-up stanzas and commands. I only know the old notation that comes from vconfig/vlan with ethY.XX and I am not sure how this plays with new bridge commands; that's why I use all the post-up/pre-down.
Here comes the interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0


auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-slaves eth0 eth1
    bond-mode balance-xor
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-updelay 200
    bond-downdelay 200
    bond-xmit-hash-policy layer3+4


auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports bond0
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_vlan_aware yes

    address 10.233.202.2/22
    gateway 10.233.200.254

    post-up ip link set br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
    post-up ip link set br0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 1
    post-up ip link set br0 type bridge nf_call_ip6tables 1
    post-up ip link set br0 type bridge nf_call_arptables 1

    post-up ip link add br0p1 type veth peer br0p1c
    post-up ip link set br0p1 master br0
    post-up bridge vlan del dev br0p1 vid 1
    post-up bridge vlan add dev br0p1 vid 55 untagged pvid
    post-up bridge vlan add dev bond0 vid 55

    pre-down bridge vlan del dev bond0 vid 55
    pre-down ip link del dev br0p1


auto br0p1
iface br0p1 inet manual
```

And for iptables on the vlan interface with -m physdev do

```
modprobe br_netfilter
```

and

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged
```

Comment: on a bridge it is needed to enable arp proxy usually

Comment: Typo, sorry. Should be veth. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: @A.B So, it does not make any sense to you? How would you set up such a bridge, using these commands? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @djdomi Did already try enabling proxy arp. Does not help.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov My notes show that I already tried the version with PVID, but...  You know when things start getting weird, when getting impatient, when you start pulling out your hair, when it's getting late, you start losing focus, when you drop notes, puhhh.
PVID - that did the trick. I thank you very much!

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I moved parts of this "blob of commands" into the interfaces file using post-up etc. I was not aware that I can set up interfaces file with bridge vlan etc without using iproute2_ng, but with native interfaces stanzas. I was only aware of the old eth.XX stuff. Can I add my interfaces file to the original question and you help me form a more "sexy" interface out of that? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the "PVID" setting on the VLAN 55 on the `venet0` bridge port. It wasn't show up in the `bridge vlan show`.

You set this tag to **Egress**, which means that any untagged packet leaving the system to this interface will get tagged with VLAN 55. The missing **PVID** setting does the reverse: it tells the system to strip the VLAN tag 55 and present to the system without tags. Right now, it doesn't do this tag stripping.

To verify this, with current configuration, re-run your tcpdump command with additional `-e` switch (show Ethernet information). It should reveal that packets you see from that interface are still tagged; that's why Linux ignores them.

Yes, as you might have already guessed, Linux is able to do asymmetric VLANs.

To enable proper tag processing (to make things symmetric — that's what you expect), use

```
bridge vlan add dev venet0 vid 55 untagged pvid
```

instead of your `bridge vlan add dev venet0 vid 55 master`.

Also, `/etc/network/interfaces` of Debian network scripts permit much more modular config that the one you've got by putting this blob of commands. It is natively able to make bonds, vlans, bridges (including vlan aware ones). Better use that, don't put this awful script raw, it defeats the purpose of the network initialization system!